# Increment version number in advanced installer

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I read a little of the help for my advanced installer 6.5.1 and couldn't find a way to change the version string except by hand.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a snippet from one of our push scripts. Rob, maybe you'll find this useful too- Advanced installer provides the ability to set the ProductVersion of your installation package based on an existing compiled EXE.  We use a custom build task in TFS to increment our build number and set our AssemblyInfo.cs files, then with the resulting main app EXE, we can do this:

```
:COMPILE_AIP

SET AIP_DIR="C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 7.1.3"

ECHO Advanced Installer Directiry: %AIP_DIR%

ECHO.
ECHO //////////////////////////
ECHO //Compiling AIP Files...//
ECHO //////////////////////////
ECHO.

ECHO Setting version on all installers...
ECHO Setting version on all installers... >> %DESTINATION_APP_DIR%_push_script_output.txt
%AIP_DIR%\advancedinstaller /edit "<pathtoaipfile>\installproject.aip" /SetVersion -fromfile <path to exe defining app version>
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO ERROR_HANDLER
```

Hope this helps-

Comment: thanks! and amazingly they  still did not develope "increase version" cli method.

Comment: Incrementing should probably be done by your build system, but as far as AI, looks like you can now set the version with a version string http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/set-version.html rather than needing to use a compiled binary

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [/SetVersion](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/set-version.html) switch to set the product version from the command line. Useful in automatic builds.

Answer (score 1):

The files for creating an MSI are usually in XML format, we've created a little tool that runs as part of our build process that goes and changes the build number manually, try openning the advanced installer file in notepad and look for the "ProductVersion" string.

Cheers,
Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Advanced Installer v9.8 it is much easier to retrieve the *Product Version* from a file: right-click in the edit box and select the “Set version from file...” menu item on the [Product Details](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/product-details-tab.html) tab. This will keep in sync the product version of the package with the version of the selected file, which can be for example your main application executable.

Cheers